# MySQL BEFORE UPDATE query is not updating correctly

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers

I have the following table and update trigger that is made of two parts - an update and a soft delete. A local variable `@account_name` is used along with the trigger. On a second update, trigger doesn't fire update correctly. For test purposes, I have `WhoTriggered` field in the table, to keep track of what part of the trigger engaged during update:

```
CREATE TABLE `CC` (
  `Id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `Name` char(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WhoTriggered` char(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` char(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedAt` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `UpdatedBy` char(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UpdatedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeletedBy` char(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeletedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER before_CC_update BEFORE UPDATE ON CC
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.deleted = 1 THEN
        SET NEW.WhoTriggered = 'SoftDelete';
        SET NEW.DeletedBy = @account_name;
        SET NEW.DeletedAt = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
    ELSE
        SET NEW.WhoTriggered = 'Update';
        SET NEW.UpdatedBy = @account_name;
        SET NEW.UpdatedAt = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Insertion, First Update and Marking the record as deleted works with no issues

```
SET @account_name = 'FirstInsert';
INSERT INTO `test`.`CC` (`Id`, `Name`, `Active`) VALUES ('123', '123', '1');

SET @account_name = 'FirstUpdate';
UPDATE `test`.`CC` SET `Name` = 'Name1' WHERE (`Id` = '123');

SET @account_name = 'MarkDeleted';
UPDATE `test`.`CC` SET `Deleted` = '1' WHERE (`Id` = '123');
```

[image]

However, I also want to track if anyone touches or tries to update record, even if it was marked as deleted, so I ran the second update:

```
SET @account_name = 'SecondUpdate';
UPDATE `test`.`CC` SET `Name` = 'Name2' WHERE (`Id` = '123');
```

[image]

It gives incorrect update. `WhoTriggered` should be `Update`, `UpdatedBy` should be `SecondUpdate`, `DeletedBy` should be `MarkDeleted`(it's old value). In other words, second update triggered the "deletion" part of the trigger, instead of "update" part of the query.

What is causing this issue and how to correct it ?

Comment: Try changing your first condition to `IF OLD.deleted = 0 AND NEW.deleted = 1`

Comment: @user1191247 Unfortunately, that solution doesn't work either. , Who column is updated to `Update` and doesn't update `DeletedBy/At` columns, they are still marked as NULL.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `IF OLD.deleted IS NULL AND NEW.deleted = 1` - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yXJC1ueo)

Comment: @user1191247
I think we have a winner. Please post the official reply, so I can accept this as answer !

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for your first condition will run whenever `new.deleted = 1`. So after you first set `deleted = 1`, it will always run this branch.  Instead change the condition to:

```
IF OLD.deleted IS NULL AND NEW.deleted = 1 THEN
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yXJC1ueo).

This is not a good use of triggers, especially with the need for your `@account_name` variable. It would almost certainly be better managed in your client application code. Just *to put in my two-penny worth*.